# Get position of map key or how to set Stepper isActive from map

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm populating stepper with a map. All is working however I'm having a problem finding out how to set 'isActive' from that map. To do that I need to compare the position of the map key with the current step variable

```
  int current = 0;
  bool complete = false;

  goTo(int step) {
    setState(() => current = step);
  }

  next() {
    current + 1 != list.length
        ? goTo(current + 1)
        : setState(() => complete = true);
  }

  cancel() {
    if (current > 0) {
      goTo(current - 1);
    }
  }

  Map<String, List<Widget>> list = {
    'Step1': [TextField(), TextField()],
    'Step2': [TextField(), TextField()]
  };

  List<Step> stepList() {
    List<Step> _steps = [];
    list.forEach((k, v) => _steps.add(Step(
          isActive: current == list.indexOf(k) ? true : false, // <-- this doesn't work
          title: Text(k),
          content: Column(
            children: v.map<Widget>((child) {
              return child;
            }).toList(),
          ),
        )));
    return _steps;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stepper(
        onStepContinue: next,
        currentStep: current,
        onStepCancel: cancel,
        steps: stepList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

In simplified version how to get the position of map key

```
class MyClass {
 Map map = {'pos1':[1,2], 'pos2':[1,2]};
  print(); //<- print position of key containing 'pos1'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will have to make a list of keys from your map

```
  List<String> keyList() {
    List<String> l = [];
    list.forEach((k, v) {
      l.add(k);
    });
    return l;
  }
```

and then use that list in your isActive property

```
isActive: current == keyList().indexOf(k) ? true : false,
```

The simplify version would probably look like this

```
void main() {
   Map _map = {'pos1':[1,2], 'pos2':[1,2]};

  List<String> _list(){
    List<String> l =[];
    _map.forEach((k,v){l.add(k);});
    return l;
  }
  print(_list().indexOf('pos1'));
}
```

But lets see if someone has a better idea

Comment: thanks... I'll wait for others if we can do it without creating a new list